# React Hook useEffect Error missing dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling, react-hooks

I’m very new to React and I’m trying to build an app, but I’m getting this error : React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: ‘getRecipes’. Either include it or remove the dependency array. I cannot figure out how to fix it.  Any help would be appreciated ?

```js
useEffect(  () => {
    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);
  
  
  
const getRecipes = async () => {
    const response = await fetch(`https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    setRecipes(data.hits);
    console.log(data.hits);
 }
 
 
 
const updateSearch = e =>  {
  setSearch(e.target.value);
}



const getSearch = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setQuery(search)
}


  return(
  
  
    <div className="App">
    
       <form onSubmit={getSearch}className="container">
         <input className="mt-4 form-control" type="text" value={search} onChange={updateSearch}/>
  <button className="mt-4 mb-4 btn btn-primary form-control" type="submit">Search</button>
       </form>
       
       <div className="recipes">
       
        {recipes.map(recipe => (
          <Recipe 
          key={recipe.label}
          title={recipe.recipe.label} image={recipe.recipe.image} 
          ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
          />
        ))}
        </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your `useEffect` calls `getRecipes();` React is indicating that `getRecipes` is a dependency on this useEffect Hook.

You could update with Effect with:

```
useEffect(() => {
    getRecipes();
}, [query, getRecipes]);
```

However you will get

`The 'getRecipes' function makes the dependencies of useEffect Hook (at line 18) change on every render. Move it inside the useEffect callback. Alternatively, wrap the 'getRecipes' definition into its own useCallback() Hook. (react-hooks/exhaustive-deps)`

So you can update to:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const getRecipes = async () => {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://api.edamam.com/search?q=${query}&app_id=${APP_ID}&app_key=${APP_KEY}`
      );
      const data = await response.json();
      setRecipes(data.hits);
      console.log(data.hits);
    };

    getRecipes();
  }, [query]);
```

Which indicates this effect will be called, when `query` is modified, which means getRecipes call the API with `query`.

Comment: Can you memoize the function so that it never changes and it doesn't need to be a dependency? Because without that, it might mean that `useEffect` gets called too many times.

Comment: how do you memoize the function? I'm very new to all of this

Comment: Yes exactly what did, move the getRecipes inside the useEffect. Thank you so much for your help